# BackHandler in React Native isn't working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

```
const RootNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Splash: {
        screen:Splash
    },
    BeforeLogin: {
        screen:BeforeLogin
    },    
    Signin: {
        screen:Signin,
    },
    Signup: {
        screen:Signup
    },
    Tabs: {
        screen:TabHolder,
    },
    ForgotPassword: {
        screen:ForgotPassword
    },
  } );
```

Below is the `BackHandler` I used in my `BeforeLogin` screen.

```
  componentWillMount() { 
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton); 
  } 
  
  componentWillUnmount() { 
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton); 
  }

  handleBackButton = () => { 
    BackHandler.exitApp(); 
  }
```

Below is the `BackHandler` I have used in my `Signin` screen and `Signup` screen.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',() => {   
 
      this.props.navigation.navigate('BeforeLogin');
      return true;

    });
  }
```

My `BeforeLogin` screen has 2 buttons. Signin and Signup which navigates me to `Signin` and `Signup` screen.

Now, there are 2 scenarios which I'm facing.

**Scenario 1:** I am on `BeforeLogin` screen and I don't navigate to either `Signin` or `Signup` screen. And now, when I press my android back buttton, it closes the app. And that's what I want, to be able to close the app when user presses back button from `BeforeLogin` screen.

**Scenario 2:** I am on `BeforeLogin` screen and I navigate to either `Signin` or `Signup` screen. And now when I go back to `BeforeLogin` screen and then press android back button, the app isn't closing now.

How can I solve my Scenario 2?

Comment: `componentWillMount() { 
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton); 
  } `  try changing this to `componentDidMount()`

Comment: @LokeshKumarMeena Jaydeep's answer worked for me. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `backhander` unnecessarily because it wan't run on `ios` devices.

Either navigate using `this.props.navigation.replace("")`

i.e. if you navigate from A to B and don't want to go back to A when back button is pressed simply don't use `this.props.navigation.navigate("B")` 
instead use `this.props.navigation.replace("B")`

or

try  `react-navigation@3.0`'s new fetaure `SwitchNavigator`.

In this by default app will close for all route screen used in switch navigator when back button is pressed.
So define all screen for which you want to exit app in SwitchNavigator and everything else in StackNavigator or whatever you use.

Comment: I used `this.props.navigation.replace('BeforeLogin');` instead of `this.props.navigation.navigate('BeforeLogin');` in `Signin` and `Signup` Screen and now my BackHandler in `BeforeLogin` screen works! Thank you :)

Comment: Also, can you please explain a bit more on why `replace` worked in my case and not `navigate`?